# Google charts script tag on JSF page causes an error

Tags: jsf, google-visualization

If I comment out the script tag, the page loads without error. I assume this is because the javascript is not XHTML compliant? If I include my own script.js, it also doesn't cause an error.

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="managedBean" />
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation xmlns:corecommon="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/core/common">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <h2>Google Charts with JSF Test</h2>
        <gc:googleChart divID="chartDiv" model="#{managedBean.chartModel}" height="500px" width="100%"/>
</composite:implementation>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting the error: 
"NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed - https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"

I think the event that loads the page interferes with the google charts library.

The problem was occurring because I was loading the page with the chart via AJAX using a  tag. Changing this to a  tag fixed the problem.

This post may solve the ajax loading issue:
[Load a Google Chart from an asynchronous AJAX response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448372/load-a-google-chart-from-an-asynchronous-ajax-response)